# My first Javascript in UIAutomation/Instruments

Tags: iphone, ios-ui-automation

I would like to automate testing of my iPhone app and I wrote a sample Javascript for the UIAutomation framework. I can't go past the first line, I get the following error:

Exception raised while running script: SyntaxError: Parse error
1: UIALogger.logStart("Beginning test");

There is something fundamentally wrong with the setup? I am using Xcode 3.2.6, iOS 4.3.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you have set the right target (app) to run.

2) Make sure you have set right Simulator version to run your target (see under popup on your target > Edit active target > Options > Simulator Configuration should be set to 4.3

Comment: JKI,There was a version mismatch. It is working now, Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, parse errors are also shown if there is a syntax error in the javascript code. I was tied down to something like this for hours one day! :(